# Best practices for using containers

Tags: user-interface, containers, vaadin

I develop a Vaadin application which has to deal with a lot of tables in its UI. Most of the tables use sensitive data which is updated frequently. 
Connectivity to the database is acquired using SQLContainers, therefore each UI table is binded to one of these SQLContainers. Some of these database tables have to be displayed in different contexts with different filters. The UI is based mostly on tabsheets so sometimes one database table has to be in a few tabs simultaneously (but with different filters). I tried updating the filters on tab selection change, but this solution doesn't look clean.

What is the best approach for displaying one database table in many places when only one of these tables is visible at any given time?

Answer (score 2):

Usually, you have different containers for different table instances. Although, in some cases, you may want to share the same container instance between different components. It is totally possible and acceptable, as long as you understand the consequences: Filtering and sorting is done on the container level, meaning, that if you apply a filter on the container in one view and then navigate to another view, the container will be filtered there as well. Not understanding this may lead to "weird bugs" and lots of WTFs.

The benefits of sharing the same container instance has to do with minimizing the memory footprint of your application - the more containers you have, the more memory you will consume. Note that both the table and the SQLContainer are lazy loading - meaning the table won't render more rows to the browser than what is needed to fill the table's area (+ some buffer), the SQLContainer won't fetch more rows than what are needed by the table --> your container won't actually contain in-memory more than a few dozen of items (* your mileage may vary).

From a performance perspective (CPU), in your case, I don't see much benefit from sharing the same container instance in multiple views, since every time you switch a view, you need to apply new filters, thus triggering a new database query and fetching the needed data every time you switch views - even when going back to a view that was previously already filtered.

So how about that best practice? Personally, I'd start with multiple container instances (one per view), do some profiling and optimize if needed. Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe it is possible to use the same container instance in multiple tables with different filter - (not 100% sure, but it's very strong instinct)

With that in mind, I'd be inclined to do something like

1. Create/use some kind of event bus to broadcast/subscribe messages saying "I've updated table XYZ"
2. Create an extension of SQLContainer overrides #fireContentsChange to broadcast when the table is updated, and that also reacts to the eventbus, calling #fireContentsChange (if the sourve of the event bus message isn't this)

There's probably a more sophisticated/better way of doing this with a single shared `Container.ItemSetChangeEvent`, but it's tricky to think this through when typing into a browser text box.

In short, on all containers, you want to propogate the `ItemSetChangeEvent` to all of the other containers that look at the same underlying table.